# Can't find the generated bulkloader.yaml

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to generate a bulkloader.yaml file in this way

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

but I get this error

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 3839, in CheckOutputFile
raise FileExistsError('%s: output file exists' % filename)
```

I can't manage to find where such file is

consider I am using Eclipse PyDev on Mac Os through the GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) you are missing the `--application=s~your_app_id` tag

2) What directory are you in when you run this?  If you are not sure run `cd path/to/where/you/want/it`

3) You can always try to find it using Mac's Spotlight, in case you are not sure where it saved.